# How to monitor SQS Redrive events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'd like to monitor the count of redrives on an SQS queue. Is there a way to see how often a message has been delivered more than once (or the average number of deliveries per message?)

Comment: What do you mean by "how often a message has been delivered"? Do you mean the number of times it has been 'Received' via a `ReceiveMessage()` call? I'm not sure if those metrics carry-over when the message is moved to a Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes. The number of receives. The number used to decide if the message has exceeded the redrive policy.  This info would help me make decisions about the redrive policy . Eg if my redrive policy is 10k and the p99 receives has been 200, I might consider dropping my redrive policy.

Answer (score 1):

The [Available CloudWatch metrics for Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) do not appear to contain any metrics related to redrives / Dead Letter Queue.

You would need to create your own metrics when retrieving messages from the Dead Letter Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think DLQ is a queue itself, so the same metrics for SQS Queue can be considered applicable for DLQ. Just may be evaluated differently.

I may have misunderstood your question too :)